# Creating polygon like dashed line in Global Mapper?

Tags: symbology, global-mapper

I need to draw polygons like a "dash line" in Global Mapper (GM). It is necessary that the polygon has beats and spaces between the dashes.

GM has a style for lines with dashes, but it's for lines and I need create polygons.

Maybe there is an option to convert the line style to a polygon?

I am using Global Mapper 16.05.

[image]

Polygon created from line by tool "create buffer arround line":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Global Mapper you can easily have a polygon with dashed border like this (see sample in the bottom of the dialog box)

[image]

And/or with diagonal cross-hatch like this

[image]

If you select white as the fill-pattern color, it will look like this

[image]

However, you can't control the thickness of the lines, so there  is no way to make it look like in your drawing.

However there is a workaround, by creating lines and then coping them to the polygon, for example I can create a line like this

[image]

And then create 20 lines perpendicular to it by right-clicking on it and selecting "Advanced feature creation options -> Create Perpendicular lines spaced along selected Lines/Areas features..."

[image]

If you choose a very large line thickness for the newly created lines, they will look like this

[image]

Then we delete the original line, select the polygon and right-click and select "Crop/Combine/Split functions -> CROP - Crop loaded features to selected area(s)..."

[image]

In the dialog box select to crop lines and the checkbox to mark as deleted the cropped features

[image]

The result should be pretty similar to your drawing, in my example it ends up looking like this

[image]

Or like this if you select to use flat endcaps for the lines

[image]

Comment: man, you are cool) did a little differently: drew a line and created perpendicular lines with an interval. Then I selected the "perpendicular" lines and created a buffer for them. After - removed all lines. I got the result what I wanted :D
https://i.stack.imgur.com/poy4g.png

Comment: @Jonny I'm glad you found a formula that worked for you. Cheers